# How to define an object that is also a function (object from interface) in one statement without type assertion?

Tags: typescript, interface, type-assertion

Since in JavaScript functions are also objects, a TypeScript interface can be both (an object and a function) at the same time, like so:

```
//TS:
interface ITest {
    (arg: any): void
    field: number
}

let test: ITest = ((arg: any) => { }) as ITest
test.field = 123
test("foo")
test.field = 456

//JS:
var test = (function (arg) { });
test.field = 123;
test("foo");
test.field = 456;
```

At the line `let test: ITest =` it won't complain that I do not obey the interface, because I do a type assertion to `ITest`. However, I'd like to define the entire object in one statement. Something like:

```
let test: ITest = { 
    ((arg: any) => { }), // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
    field: 123,
}
```

But it fails. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no way to do that without type assertions. The docs for [Hybrid Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) also use it that way e.g.

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
    let counter = <Counter>function (start: number) { };
    counter.interval = 123;
    counter.reset = function () { };
    return counter;
}

let c = getCounter();
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

Comment: @modiX Seems like type assertion is the correct way since the official docs also use it like that.